# How do I prove that if a function mapping from $ C \times C \to \Bbb R$ is continuous on $ C \times C $, then it is uniformly continuous there?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let C be the Cantor Middle Third set in [0,1]. Suppose $ f: C\times C \to \Bbb R$ is continuous on $C\times C$. Show f is uniformly continuous there.

I'm not really sure what the link is here. Somehow, C being a Cantor set means continuity implies uniform continuity, but I don't really know how to argue that.

Comment: Continuous on a compact set implies uniformly continuous.

Answer (score 1):

$C\times C$ is compact so any continuous function from it to $\mathbb{R}$ will be uniformly continuous.

Comment: of course, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Let me give the argument for a function $f\colon C\to \Bbb R$, as this extends analogously to $C\times C$. Let $\varepsilon>0$, and, for every $p\in C$, choose $\delta_p>0$ such that $|x-p|<\delta_p$ implies $|f(x)-f(p)|<\varepsilon$. The sets $(p-\delta_p,p+\delta_p)$ form an open cover of $C$ as $p$ ranges over all points in $C$, and by compactness there is a finite subcover corresponding to points $p_1,\ldots p_n$. Simply take $\delta=\min\{\delta_{p_1},\ldots, \delta_{p_n}\}$ and you're done.

Now repeat this using open balls in $C\times C$, etc. Or prove once and for all that continuous functions on compact sets are uniformly continuous (or cite this fact, depending on the class).